# Extend React lifecycle hook (e.g add a print statement on every ComponentDidMount)

Tags: reactjs

I want to add some behaviour on a given lifecycle hook of a React application.

For example, adding a `console.log('Component is mounted')` on **every** `ComponentDidMount` of all the components of an application, without having to define it in every one of them (as a decorator for example), sort of like a global extender of that method that adds some code to it. Like that: [Extending Vue Lifecycle Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876597/extending-vue-lifecycle-hooks) but for React.

Anyone has an idea on how to achieve that? Cheers!

Comment: nice and very useful question, let me think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [hoc](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html). In the root app, apply the higher order component.

Example:

```
const withMountHOC = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log('mounted');
    }
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }
}

export default withMountHOC;
```

In your app component:

```
const WrappedApp = withMountHOC(App);
ReactDOM.render(
  WrappedApp,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Since the **parent** `componentDidMount` hook is called after **child** `componentDidMount` hook, the **HOC** `componentDidMount` will be applied in any nested level of the component.

---

You may also be interested to see this blog: [Replacing Mixins in React](https://medium.com/denver-devs/replacing-mixins-in-react-1f78ff567919).

Answer (score 0):

create **CustomComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class CustomComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super();
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('component is mounted');
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CustomComponent
```

Now create **MyComponent.js** that extends **CustomComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CustomComponent from './CustomComponent'

class MyComponent extends CustomComponent {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello from MyComponent
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

now you see console , you have log : `"component is mounted"`

but if you write `componentDidMonunt()` inside `MyComponent.js` , you will get log from  **MyComponent.js**