# Cross Cutting Concept in react life cycle methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I want add some behavior on a given lifecycle method of a React application without having to define it in every one of them?

I came from Java world and have been trying to use HOC for printing/console at every react component life cycle methods similar to AOP concept in Spring/Javaor you can say universal cross cutting on life cycle methods like componentWillUnmount, componentDidMount, componentWillMount... I want to console component name and lifecyle methods name.

Example

Component B componentWillMount called

Component A componentWillMount called

Component B componentDidMountcalled ...

I have tried to use HOC correct me if am wrong but it seems I will be forced to pass all components through this function.

[Extend React lifecycle hook (e.g add a print statement on every ComponentDidMount)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757094/extend-react-lifecycle-hook-e-g-add-a-print-statement-on-every-componentdidmoun) similar question was asked before but the solution only prints the parent components life cycle but not the child?

Thank you for your help and I really appreciate if you include a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution in React that I can think of would be to create a new base class that extends the base React Component class. Add the lifecycle method into the base class and then every component you create extends this new class if you want it to use the lifecycle method.

```
class NewBaseClass extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('do something on mount')
  }
}

class CustomComponent extends NewBaseClass {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

I havent tested this exact use case let me know if it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for quick response. The issue with this approach is this only works to the component that is extending the base class but not to the child components. Correct me if am wrong but this approach requires me to extends every single component from NewBaseClass. I was trying similar thing with HOC but again I believe HOC will also require me to make changes at every class component. Check this if you get a min https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-lifecycle-logger-forked-txt74?file=/src/loggify.js&codemirror=1

Comment: Yep you are correct you would need to extend every single child component, but anyway if you are using class components you would be extending them from the React.Component class, whereas Hoc would add more code.

But yes you are correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) similar to the following:

```js
function withLifeCycleLogs(WrappedComponent) {
  const Enhanced = class extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log(`Component ${WrappedComponent.name} did mount`);
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      console.log(`Component ${WrappedComponent.name} did update`, {
        // Uncomment below lines to inspect props change
        // prevProps,
        // nextProps: this.props
      });
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
      console.log(`Component ${WrappedComponent.name} will unmount`);
    }
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
  // Wrap the display name for easy debugging
  // https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-wrap-the-display-name-for-easy-debugging
  Enhanced.displayName = `WithLifeCylceLogs${getDisplayName(WrappedComponent)}`;

  // Static Methods Must Be Copied Over
  // https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#static-methods-must-be-copied-over
  // 
  // hoistNonReactStatic(Enhanced, WrappedComponent);
  return Enhanced;
}

function getDisplayName(WrappedComponent) {
  return WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name || "Component";
}

class Counter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.increment}>Increment</button>
        <p>{this.props.counter}</p>
        <button onClick={this.props.unmount}>Unmount Counter</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const CounterContainer = withLifeCycleLogs(Counter);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
      counterVisible: true
    };
  }

  increment = () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({ ...state, counter: state.counter + 1 }));
  };

  unmountCounter = () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({ ...state, counterVisible: false }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        {this.state.counterVisible && (
          <CounterContainer
            counter={this.state.counter}
            increment={this.increment}
            unmount={this.unmountCounter}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const AppContainer = withLifeCycleLogs(App);


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```

Yes, you need to pass every component to `withLifeCycleLogs` function. But this is really simple and does not use much space, check this out:

```
class AwesomeComponent extends React.Component {
  //
}

export default withLifeCylceLogs(AwesomeComponent);
```

It's like using annotation in Spring (correct me if I'm wrong)

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-dew-jvdiw?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Thank you @glinda93 for detailed explanation & yes I agree with your answer but lets say you are working on a existing react SPA & you want to add logger to all life cycle methods. I know one option is to make changes on the entire component of the application files and pass them through custom HOC. But Is there a way to make the HOC related configuration & it will get automatically applied to all components on application start? What would your solution be if you face the above scenario? What would be the easiest & cleaner way to add logger for all life cycle methods for existing application?

Comment: @HENOK I understand your situation. I think it's not desirable to add logger to all lifecylcle methods. If you're using redux, you can consider redux devtools or redux-logger. If that's not the solution, consider React.Children.map and React.cloneElement. I think they're the only way to convert all children to have life cycle loggers. I was trying to answer the question with that methods. But it was too complicated for my free time. But I think it's possible.